# optimizing a delete query for table with no index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Let's say we have the following tables:
r(a, b, c)
where a is some integer, and the table has 50 rows
s(d, e, f, a)
s.a is a foreign key onto t.a.
each tuple is 400 bytes and s is a multiset since this is a SQL database.
s holds about 1 million tuples. 
when a table is added, the database server automatically creates an index on the primary-­‐key columns in the table so for example t has an index on a. However, Oracle does not create indexes on columns that are foreign keys. So s has no index.
We want to delete 15 rows from t. So here is what we do:
1) We remove rows from s that have the same a values in t. This takes 10 minutes.
2) Then we run the statement DELETE FROM t WHERE a IN (values we are trying to remove, 15 of them to be exact)
This takes about 6 hours.

So my guess is the second step takes a long time because for every tuple in t, we are comparing the value of a to every value within the query list. So how can we optimize this query to get the same result but much faster!?

Comment: *However, Oracle does not create indexes on columns that are foreign keys. So s has no index* Add one?

Comment: how does adding an index to s help? i mean if it is t that we are dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use joins For CRUD Operations will be faster rather than using IN or subquery

For eg:

```
DELETE FROM t 
INNER JOIN S ON t.a = S.a
```

Hope this helps

Comment: have u created the index for those two tables

Comment: "will be faster"? Not necessarily, it depends on the query planner. A good query planner will produce the same query plan for equivalent queries.